# How do I copy a symbolic link?

Tags: centos, symlink, cp

I have a symbolic link to a file in one directory.  I would like to have that same link in another directory.  How do I copy a symbolic link?

I tried to cp the symbolic link but this copies the file it points to instead of the symbolic link itself.

Comment: Does `cp` on CentOS support `-P` or `--no-dereference` switch?

Comment: @manatwork: Thanks it does just found that.  If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Use `cp -P` (capital P) to never traverse any symbolic link and copy the symbolic link instead.

This can be combined with other options such as `-R` to copy a directory hierarchy — `cp -RL` traverses all symbolic links to directories, `cp -RP` copies all symbolic links as such. `cp -R` might do one or the other depending on the unix variants; GNU `cp` (as found on CentOS) defaults to `-P`.

Even with `-P`, you can copy the target of a symbolic link to a directory on the command line by adding a `/` at the end: `cp -RP foo/ bar` copies the directory tree that `foo` points to.

GNU `cp` has a convenient `-a` option that combines `-R`, `-P`, `-p` and a little more. It makes an exact copy of the source (as far as possible), preserving the directory hierarchy, symbolic links, permissions, modification times and other metadata.

Comment: Beware that once copied/moved, a symlink might become broken (if the source is a symlink to a relative path).

Comment: is there a way to prevent breaking the symlinks if you are moving to a higher or lower directory?

Comment: As a note: "GNU `cp`" is not the same thing as `gcp`, which I use.  `gcp -P` is currently broken, even in 2019.  (sigh).

Comment: On a mac `cp -a` works, but `cp -P`  doesn't

Answer (score 2):

Check this answer https://superuser.com/a/315757/53590 for a specifically CentOS take on the problem. The whole question might help you but the bit at the bottom is specifically CentOS.

Comment: Note that others may choose a different order than yours for listing the answers. Beside that, the order may change in time. Please post a direct link to the referred answer. (Click the “share” link below that answer and copy the direct link which appears.)